# Installing Ubuntu 12.04 using freeDOS through USB

Tags: 12.04, installation, boot, 64-bit

I bought a notebook yesterday which contains freeDOS.
I followed the instructions and created a bootable USB drive.
When I boot my laptop, I select my pendrive to boot.
It gives three options:
1-Try ubuntu without installing
2-Install ubuntu
3-disk check

Selecting anything gives me a blank screen.The LED in my pendrive doesnt even blink.

I am trying to install 12.04
My laptop is a intel 2nd generation i5 processor.Can I install 64bit version or 32bit version??

Comment: How did you create the bootable USB?

Comment: Using USBinstaller from pendrivelinux.com...it was given in the creating Bootable USBdive using Windows in ubuntu.com...I have a  desktop with Windows xp...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way [Click Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStickQuick)

Installation/FromUSBStickQuick

Quick Guide: Installing Ubuntu from a USB memory stick

This guide will help you install Ubuntu on your computer by using a USB memory stick. USB memory sticks are sometimes known as flash drives, memory pens or USB Mass Storage devices.

Installing from a memory stick is useful if you have a computer without a CD drive (such as a netbook), or prefer the convenience of a memory stick. Alternative methods are available, like installing Ubuntu from inside Windows.

It should take around 30 minutes to complete this process, plus the time it takes to download the 700MB installer file. Downloading from a torrent is by far the fastest way of getting it.

This guide will assume that you are running Windows. More comprehensive documentation which covers other operating systems is available at Installation/FromUSBStick.

<sup>Sources: [help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStickQuick)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was able to boot ubuntu properly. Thanks a lot.